# Trying to expand width of rows in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How do I expand a the width of a row to be 100% of its containing div. I have the following configuration and cannot get the row to expand to the width of parent container. The BS4 documentation state using w-100 but this does not work. Neither does adding the d-inline-block. Thank you.

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/dyyqydB)

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.col-12 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">CONTAINER
  <div class="row w-100">ROW
    <div class="col-12">COL-12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add width to the classes.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 90%; /* optional not needed */

}

.row {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.col-12 {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">CONTAINER
  <div class="row">ROW
    <div class="col-12">COL-12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```